# How to export enums from rollup project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rollup

I have a package from where I am exporting enums
*Animation.ts*

```
enum AnimationType {
    FADEIN = 'fadein',
    FADEOUT = 'fadeout',
    BLINK = 'blink',
    SHAKE = 'shake',
    WIGGLE = 'wiggle',
}

export {AnimationType};
```

This is my rollup config file

```
export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: false,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: false,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      json({compact: true}),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      filesize(),
      postcss({
            writeDefinitions: true,
            plugins:[autoprefixer],
        })
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts()],
  },
];
```

I am exporting it as a package but I am not able to import enums. I am getting this error when importing
*Module has no exported member 'AnimationType'.ts(2305)*

How to resolve this error.

Answer (score -1):

In short, you can define your enum like this

```
export const AnimationType ={
    FADEIN : 'fadein',
    FADEOUT : 'fadeout',
    BLINK : 'blink',
    SHAKE : 'shake',
    WIGGLE : 'wiggle'
} as const;

// intentionally naming the variable the same as the type
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-redeclare
export type AnimationType = typeof AnimationType[keyof typeof AnimationType];
```

you can view these posts [1](https://kelly-kh-woo.medium.com/typescript-enum-const-e77ee6f7a760),[2](https://bargsten.org/jsts/enums/)  for more details